# How to auto count number and auto add comma per rows ( start from number i want )

Tags: php

Example:
I have 16 rows:

```
Row-1
Row-2
Row-3
Row-4
...
Row-16
```

After i put 16 rows in the form and put the start number ( like 17 ), I want it will auto add comma and count from number 17 to -> 32

So result will be

```
17,Row-1
18,Row-2
19,Row-3
20,Row-4
...
32,Row-16
```

Thank for helping !

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, edit your question to also include any code.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to format your 16 rows: Row-1, Row-2...Row-16.

```
function addPrefix(&$value,$key) {
    $value = "Row-".$value;
}

$row    =   range(1,16);

array_walk($row, 'addPrefix');     // Function to create an array of elements Row-1, Row-2, Row-3, Row-4...Row-16

/* You may ignore the above functions in case you already have a previously set up array */

$count = 17;

foreach($row as $r) {

    $result[]   =   $count.",".$r;
    $count++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.